# Trying to create an array with commas and semicolans

Tags: php, email

I want to create a loop for my mail system that uses the format

```
stan.smith@americandadcia.fx, Stan Smith
```

So that I can pass it through my function

```
function SendEmail($to,$fromName, $subject, $message)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    $mail->Host = smtp_host;
    $mail->Port = smtp_port;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = smtp_protocol;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = smtp_user;
    $mail->Password = smtp_pass;
    $mail->setFrom(smtp_user, $fromName);
    $mail->addReplyTo(smtp_user, $fromName);
    $mail->addAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->msgHTML($message);
    $mail->send();
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } 


}
```

This code is to go through a loop, so say you have
Stan Smith, Roger Smith and Francine Smith the form input would have

```
stan.smith@americandad.fx, Stan Smith; roger.smith@amongyou.ufo, Roger Smith; francine.smith@desperatehousewives.fox, Francine Smith
```

The addresses would then be passed into my functions file and ran through the function to send the email

```
    $mail = new MailSystem();
    $emails=$_POST['emailTo'];
    $email=explode(";",$emails);
    foreach($email as $address) {
    echo $mail->SendEmail($address, SITE_NAME." Newsletter", $_POST['emailSubject'], $_POST['emailBody']);
    }
```

My Problem is that when the email attempts to send it's going to try to run `$mail->addAddress($address)` and I get the response that it's an invalid address. I can go in and manually set the addAddress with `my email", "My name"` but when it goes through this way it resolves to invalid address.

Comment: rtfm: [AddAddress()](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=methods). it's got two arguments: `($address, $name)`. you're shoving BOTH name and address into just the `$address` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [`addAddress()`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addAddress) you have to split the receiver name and address. Your function should look like the following:

```
function SendEmail($to,$fromName, $subject, $message)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    $mail->Host = smtp_host;
    $mail->Port = smtp_port;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = smtp_protocol;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = smtp_user;
    $mail->Password = smtp_pass;
    $mail->setFrom(smtp_user, $fromName);
    $mail->addReplyTo(smtp_user, $fromName);

    //split the to on , to get mail address and receiver name.
    $address = explode(',', $to);

    //check if the name is available.
    if (!isset($address[1])) {
        $mail->addAddress($address[0]);
    } else {
        $mail->addAddress($address[0], $address[1]);
    }

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->msgHTML($message);

    //remove the following line because duplicate sending!!!
    //$mail->send();

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Works great with two emails, Time to work on the duplicate sending.

Comment: Awesome! That fixed that issue; Thanks a ton; you're a lifesaver.